# Get image dimensions after resizing

Tags: javascript, html

I have encountered a problem that other people had in this website before but none of the solutions helped me slightly.

I have a method that updates an image inside a div (read: user uploads a new image) where the image is resized to fit the set proportions (max-height and max-width are 45x45). I have to resize the div that holds the image to 2* it's dimensions such as the example below:

Original image is 180x180.

It is resized to 45x45. Div has to be 90x90.

Code is as follows:

```
function uploadThumbnail(id, xCoord, yCoord) {
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("thumbnailLoader"+id).files[0]);    
oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    var mapThumbnail = updateMapThumbnail(oFREvent.target.result, id);
    var mapContainer = document.getElementById("thumbnail"+id);
    var informationContainer = document.getElementById("container"+id);

    console.log(mapThumbnail.width);
    mapContainer.removeChild(document.getElementById("mapThumbnail"+id));
    informationContainer.removeChild(document.getElementById("infoThumbnail"+id));

    informationContainer.insertBefore(updateInfoThumbnail(oFREvent.target.result, id), informationContainer.firstChild);
    mapContainer.appendChild(mapThumbnail);
  };
};

function updateMapThumbnail(result, id){
    var newThumbnail = document.createElement("img");

    newThumbnail.src = result;
    newThumbnail.style.maxWidth = "45px";
    newThumbnail.style.maxHeight = "45px";
    newThumbnail.id = "mapThumbnail" + id;

    return newThumbnail;
}
```

As you can see I added a console.log method there for test purposes. The problem I am facing is that generating `mapThumbnail` with set max dimensions (45x45) still has the height and width attributes set with the original image size. I tried reading image.height/width and image.style.height/width as well as naturalHeight/width and clientHeight/width.

None of these solutions return the height and width after resizing.

Thanks for your time.

**Also, please refrain from offering solutions that require JavaScript libraries.**

Edit: forgot to mention that the image placed inside the div is re-sized to the dimensions that I do want it to be. It's just the attributes that seem to be wrong.

Comment: Logging the `mapThumbnail` object shows that the image encoding holds the full information (read: the whole byte64 encoding before re-sizing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four different and undependant widths on an image:

1) `img.naturalWidth` is the width in px the original image file has. It doesn't change when you set the other widths to some value. This value is rendered when the others are not defined.

2) `img.width` is an attribute of img. You find it inside the html img tag and can set it with `img.setAttribute('width', 'value')`. It doesn't change when the others are set to some value. This value is rendered when 3) is not defined and 4) is >= img.width or not defined.

3) `img.style.width` is a css-property of the images style. You can set it in your css or into the style-attribute in the img tag with `img.style.width = 'value';`. It doesn't change when the others are set to some value. This value is rendered when it is <= 4) or 4) is not defined.

4) `img.style.max-width` is another css-property of images style. You can set it in your css or into the style-attribute in the img tag with `img.style.maxWidth = 'value';`. It doesn't change when the others are set to some value. This is rendered when 2) or 3) are not defined or have values > 4).

So you have to decide by yourself which value you want to receive or set.

Its the same with **height**, there are also four heights.

**EDIT** According to your comment:
Inside your function `updateMapThumbnail` you create a new img. A newly created img has no .width unless you define it with `newThumbnail.setAttribute('width', 'value)`. Same with `img.style.width`: unless you set it explicitely somewhere it's simply not there.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply and clarification. I already had some of these in mind. I considered using style.width/height methods but for some reason in this particular case they return an empty value.

Comment: Yes sir. I did read it, appreciate the effort. I do understand the concept of not having set any dimension on the new img object, but since the proportions will not always be 45x45 I can not hardcode any expressions to fit my solution. I am honestly out of ideas, I mean, I would have to set the dimensions after re-sizing it, but if there is no grabbing these values since height/width are not set and the CSS properties are empty, I'd probably have to end up writing a different method.

Comment: Also I just realized that I forgot to add this as an answer. It does not solve my problem but makes it clear where my problem is, which comes in pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:
`console.log(getComputedStyle(mapThumbnail).width);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I just tried that and it returns an empty value.

Comment: So based on Martin Ernst's answer you should really be checking for the "maxWidth" value when console logging. http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2013/reading-max-width-cross-browser

Comment: I quote Martin "2)img.width... ...It doesn't change when the others are set to some value."

Comment: Apologies for the miscomprehension then. I tried using style.width/height as well (even before posting this very thread) and my results were the same.